# get element in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript, protractor

I am trying to use protractor to get text from several pages, however the recursion seems not working...

The idea is:

1. getText() from elements with the same "name"
2. push the text into an array
3. browser.wait until the push is completed, and then check if the next page button is enable.
4. If enabled, go to the next page, and call the function again (keep pushing text in the next page to the array).

The codes are (coffeescript):

```
  # define function getMyList
  getMyList = (CL, CLTemp) ->
    console.log "In function"
    tabs = element.all(By.css "[name='some selector']").map((elm) -> elm.getText())
    tabs.then((text) -> 
      CL.push text
      return)

    browser.wait(->
      CL.length != CLTemp.length).then ->
         console.log CL.length
         nextPage = element(By.css "[title='Next Page']")
         # hasClass is a function determining if the button is enabled or not
         return hasClass("[title='Next Page']", 'disabled').then (class_found) ->
           if class_found
              console.log CL
              return CL
           else
              console.log "Enabled"
              CLTemp = CL
              # scroll down to the button
              browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", nextPage.getWebElement()).then ->
                nextPageGo = element(By.css "[title='Next Page'] span[class=ng-binding]")
                nextPageGo.click().then -> 
                  getMyList (CL, CLTemp)
           return
         return
       return


  # Run the function. myList = [] and myListTemp = []
  getMyList (myList, myListTemp)
```

The results print:

> ```
> In function
> 1
> Enabled
> In function
> ```

Meaning it can run to the first recursion (i.e., goes to the next page), but stops at getting text of second page?

I've scratched my head for two days but still cannot figure out why the recursion is not working...

I am new to protractor. It will be great if I can get some hints!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share Website ?

Comment: I just found that it might be the time out problem. The codes work well when the "next page" loaded smoothly and quickly....(when I have a better Internet and luck!) I've tried increasing the timeout time, but then it shows up "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 s." The website I've been scraping is www.bigschedules.com.

Comment: Good. So your problem is solved? Or else you need some help ?

Comment: I am wondering that is there a better way to handle the time out problem? Or I can only increase the time out limit?

Comment: browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element ,8000).thenCatch(function () {
                      assert.fail(' element is not click able');
              });


Here element for you can be : nextPage or nextPageGo .

Comment: Thanks, Kishan! I will try it out.

Comment: Keep this for your refernece :

http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks!